# Tips on how Stan behaves and what that tells us?

Tags: stan

I'm using Rstan if that matters.

Stan lets us run in a variational mode and in a sampling mode, with the variational mode being much faster. My question is if the behavior of variational Stan can give any clues about our model.

The variational mode has several kinds of behaviors and I wonder if they might give a clue that something's not right with our model and perhaps even what that something is. For example:

1. We can get an error during eta adaptation.
2. We can get an error during gradient ascent, usually before any iterations, but occasionally during later iterations.
3. We can get a divergence in gradient ascent -- i.e. the delta ELBO mean explodes.
4. We can have the delta ELBO mean/median increase above the initial 1.0, but then decrease until convergence.
5. We have have the delta ELBO mean/median decrease from 1.0, but take more or fewer iterations.
6. We can have the delta ELBO mean or median or both converge (i.e. go below 0.01).

I'm thinking of rules of thumb. As an example when sampling, if I have a reasonably-sized data set and a fairly simple model but it takes an unreasonably long time to sample, my first thought is to check my priors. I've seen this kind of behavior when I leave the priors at the default (flat, improper priors), and often times this is fixed by placing a fairly vague prior on things to keep the sampler out of implausible parts of sample space.

Anyone have rules of thumb or insights for meanfield mode -- both in its own right and how it might relate to sampling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is fair to say we are farther along with diagnostics for MCMC than for variational Bayes. The VB algorithms in Stan attempt to find the closest multivariate normal distribution to the posterior distribution of the parameters in the unconstrained space. That can fail, either because the closest multivariate normal distribution to the posterior distribution is not actually found by the iterative algorithm or because the posterior distribution in the unconstrained space is not well-approximated by a multivariate normal.

One rule of thumb is that you should run VB multiple times. A second rule of thumb, it seems to me, is that Stan will sample very efficiently from a posterior distribution that is approximately multivariate normal. So, if MCMC is slow, either you have millions of data points or the posterior distribution is not approximately multivariate normal (or both). VB might be preferable in the former case but is unlikely to be so in the latter case.

We have evaluated VB a good bit on the collection of example models. It seems better at generating good predictions than recovering the parameters (using the posterior mean and standard deviation to construct a z-score for a VB estimate). It seems to do better on models that do not have scale parameters.

Particularly with the meanfield variant --- which tries to find the closest uncorrelated multivariate normal distribution to the posterior --- it is almost required that you do a lot of reparameterizations to make the parameters less correlated in the posterior distribution. That is one reason why rstanarm recommends specifying the `QR = TRUE` argument for meanfield (and for other estimation algorithms), which reduces the posterior correlations in the coefficients by orthogonalizing the predictors with a QR decomposition and then inverting the transformation after the draws have been obtained.

Comment: Thanks, very insightful! So if MCMC seems slow and we're talking (only) 10's of thousands of rows of data, VB might not really buy us anything. Also, I was not taking precautions for meanfield, which was a mistake.

Comment: To elaborate, if you do have a uncorrelated normal posterior, it looks like the treedepth would be 3, as in this Stan program: `'parameters { vector[100] theta; } model { target += normal_lpdf(theta | 0, 1); }'`. So, the wall time is something like `(time to evaluate the gradient) x (2^3 - 1) x iterations`. When MCMC takes a long time, it is almost always because the treedepth is near 10 and the wall time is `(time to evaluate the gradient) x (2^10 - 1) x iterations`. Meanfield is only a free lunch when the linear terms in the time calculation dominate the polynomial number of leapfrog steps.